# Lords & Ladies: Gossip Card Timing and Servant Actions

Tags: lords-and-ladies

**How does the timing work when playing gossip cards on servants with actions?** More specifically, I targeted a cook with Forbidden Love which was immediately confirmed by another player. In reaction, the player wanted to use the Cook's ability which allows him to switch gossip cards with another player, which would then remove the cook from play.

Under the "Confirming Gossip" section on pg. 9 of [the rules](http://www.lordsandladiesgame.com/files/lords+ladies_rulebook_CurrentVersion.pdf), it states:

> If Gossip is confirmed, the Gossip card's action is immediately taken by the player it has been played on.

However, under the "Additional Servant Rules" on pg. 8, it states:

> One time powers can be used anytime in the game but the servant is then fired...

So how is this resolved? It seems to me that the player would not be able to use the Cook's ability until after the gossip had been resolved, which would give each of the gossipers a gossip token. The player I targeted feels that he should have been able to interrupt the gossip action and use his cook's ability, effectively removing his cook from play, switching hands with a player, and preventing anyone from getting gossip tokens.

Is there an official ruling for the timing of these actions?